# Memory footprint way too large

Tags: php

I have tried the memory usage of some simple variables and encounter unexpected results, please see this code:

```
        $datetimes = [];
        $memory_before = memory_get_usage();

        for ($x = 0; $x < 1000; $x++) {
            $datetimes[] = new \DateTime();
        }
        var_dump('DateTimes: ' . (memory_get_usage() - $memory_before));


        $ints = [];
        $memory_before = memory_get_usage();

        for ($x = 0; $x < 1000; $x++) {
            $ints[] = $x;
        }
        var_dump('Integers: ' . (memory_get_usage() - $memory_before));
```

I get this output (on PHP 7.4, 64bit):

```
string(17) "DateTimes: 350504"
string(15) "Integers: 37160"
```

37 KB memory for 1000 ints does not make sense to me, right? I'd expect 8000 byte plus some array overhead.

My experiment scales: for a million ints, I get 33558808 byte memory usage.

I have disabled xdebug.

Comment: If you want a more accurate view of memory usage, you'll probably want to invoke the garbage collector before and after your test.  I'm not a PHP guy, but perhaps read up on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php

Comment: Each iteration of `$ints[] = $x;` eventually needs to extend the array, which involves a copy of the full array. So the memory contains 1000 arrays of size 0-1000 (in the worst case).

Comment: The first integers already take a fixed memory size of 376 (up to `$x < 8`), so I think this does not scale as you would expect it

Answer (score 7):

It's how PHP works and the disadvantage of having dynamically-typed variables.

The integer is in reality a [Zend object](https://www.zend.com/basic-php-structures).

1000 x (64 * 2) = 128 Kbit so 16KB.

Add to that the array of size 1000.

> In memory, zval is represented as two 64-bit words. The first word keeps the value — and the second word keeps the type, type_flags, extra, and reserved fields.

Comment: 1000 items * (64 bits * 2) = 128kBit or 16 kByte, but this does explain quite a bit about why it's much larger than expected.